# C# - Perform UPLOAD and DOWNLOAD in ONE web request to Node.js server

Tags: c#, node.js, http, download, postman

I have a Node.js server set up with a route that receives a file upload (in a POST request), and returns a file download.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        // Do stuff with files

        // Return a download
        res.status(200);
        res.download('pathtofile');
    });
});
```

I test it with Postman. It looks like Postman can post a file and receive the  file download.

So wonder how to do that with C# in one web request.

Comment: I don't know any c#, but postman has a `c#` code generation. On your postman request: `Code > C# (RestSharp)`

Comment: WOW. I never knew such a thing. THANKS.